# Autolayout constraints not applied

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

This is my constraints for the label, however it doesn't seem to be affecting it and the location of the label is always at the top left. Have i missed out a step or made an mistake?

How can I make the label to be positioned in the center?

[image]

Comment: It's completely right based on your constraint, what did you expect?

Comment: Base on your constraint it's pretty logic. if you want your label to be centered just `label.textAlignment = .center`

Answer (score 0):

To make your label text perfectly in centre, Remove

> Lock Name Lbl.leading = leadingMargin - 8

Leave the remaining two constraints as the following work on there basis which is:

```
Lock Name Lbl.centerY  = superview.centerY
Lock Name Lbl.centerX  = superview.centerX
```

Add these two more constraints:

```
Lock Name Lbl.width  = superview.width /* Or desired width */
Lock Name Lbl.height = superview.height /* Or desired height */
```

And don't forget to your align label text to centre.

For multiple line set no. of lines to 0 and the following constraint will applied(I Always recommends it to use):

```
Lock Name Lbl.centerX  = superview.centerX
Lock Name Lbl.width    = superview.width /* Or desired width */
Lock Name Lbl.top      = superview.top
Lock Name Lbl.bottom   = superview.bottom
```

And as you using tableview so use this tableview delegate function with a line of code inside viewdidload inside your UITableViewController class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```